# Is it possible to place a link within a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to place a link within a `title` attribute? In the example below I want "Click here" to link to google.com. My reason for wanting this is because my `title` attribute contents are placed as a caption under my photos.

```
title="Click here for Google"
```

Comment: you can write in the `title` whatever you want, but it wont act as an `href`

Comment: you should say which js lib are you using to make your img title a caption, maybe in the manual you can find a solution

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. As the title will appear as a small tooltip while the user hovers the mouse in the component where the `title` attribute is placed in, this tooltip will fade out as soon as the user moves the mouse out of the object.

As it would be needed that the user moves the mouse from the object into the tooltip, it would disappear as soon as the user tries to click the link, so this behavior is not possible.

If you try using an HTML tag in your `title` attribute it will show up as usual text, such as in the screenshot below.

[image: Example]

---

***Note:** If you want to have exactly this behavior, I suggest you use a framework such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and try to make use of the [popover component](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), through the `trigger` attribute, to show automatically as a tooltip and cover your needs. Or adapt the [tooltip component](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options) not to hide automatically when the mouse moves out of the focused component.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't add *HTML* tags in the `title=""` attribute. But you can make another element "behave" like a title attribute and display the link when the image is hovered :

```css
img, img:hover + a, a:hover{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
}
a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here for google</a>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what the OP asked for, but is an interesting solution depending on the need.